# Using 60 frames per second causes the screen to leave trail of textures in LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, render, frame-rate

I'm trying to implement a frame rate feature, and I have noticed that using 60 frames per second causes the screen to leave a drawn trail of textures when there is movement.

Here's the code I'm using to make the frame rate feature:

```
public void render(float deltaT){

   currentLevel.updateWorld(deltaT);

   if((fps+=deltaT) >= 1.0/60.0){
       fps = 0;
   }else
       return;

   super.render(deltaT);
   Gdx.gl.glClearColor(103 / 255f, 69 / 255f, 117 / 255f, 1);
   Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

   currentLevel.updateScreen(deltaT, gameCamera);
}
```

The currentLevel.updateWorld updates the game's logic. The currentLevel.updateScreen method updates the camera's position and draws the screen.

Comment: I think libgdx automatically manages fps for you. you do not need to force it

Comment: Doesn't it manage the number of render calls? If the game didn't lose time needlessly running code to update the screen the actual game logic could be sped up, and the game would run more smoothly .

Comment: What is this "frame rate feature" supposed to be doing? On a screen locked to 60Hz refresh (all phones and some monitors), the current logic is set up to give every other frame of animation a ~50% chance of not being rendered, resulting in very erratic frame rate. As for the ghosting, I suspect you accidentally drew something in `updateWorld()`